# How to make a web service for asp.net web api built using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, web-services, entity-framework-4, restful-architecture

I have built an asp.net Web API project and I want to make a web service to access this api on different platforms (mobile, web). I am new to web services and have to learn it from scratch. Can anyone explain me in detail the whole process.

My web api goes like:

```
namespace EUClientVisitAPI.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Event")]
    public class EventController : ApiController
    {
        private EUClientVisitEntities db = new EUClientVisitEntities();

        // GET: api/Event
        public IQueryable Gettb_Event()
        {
             db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;         

             var eventDetails = (from e in db.tb_Event
                                 select new
                                      {
                                          e.EventID,
                                          e.tb_Customer.CustomerName,
                                          e.StartDate,
                                          e.EndDate,
                                          loc = (from l in db.tb_EventLocation where l.EventID == e.EventID select new { l.tb_Location.LocationName }).Distinct(),
                                          e.Objective
                                      });

            return (IQueryable)eventDetails;
    }     

    [Route("EventDetails")]
    public IQueryable GetEventDetails()
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        var customerList = (from c in db.tb_Customer
                            join e in db.tb_Event
                            on c.CustomerID equals e.CustomerID
                            join el in db.tb_EventLocation
                            on e.EventID equals el.EventID
                            select  new
                            {
                                 el.LocationID
                            }).Distinct();

        return (IQueryable)customerList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I offer you implement Restfull service

Comment: A "Web API" **IS** a web service .....

Comment: @marc_s how to access this web api from different machine?

Comment: if you want use it , i can help you and send complete answer

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh- Yes sure, it would be very helpful to me.

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh- basically I have built this api for a mobile app. So basically I have to access this data from that app, so if you could please provide me a solution

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh I am waiting for the solution friend?

Comment: @prabhjot Yes please wait

Answer (score 0):

**First.** create your Web API In The your Web Application.
for this  work you must implement [RestFul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) Service(Get,Post,Put,Delete)
**second.** Host Your Web Application and database in server

in the your Mobile App(ex. *Xamarin* )

With Web API Url Get Your Data.

Example:

**Web Application**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/person")]
public class PrsonApiController : ApiController
{ 
  [httpGet]
  [Route("Person/all")]
  public  IHttpActionResult Get()
  {
    return context.Person.ToList();
  }

}
```

In Your Mobile App Send request to this Url `www.example.com/api/person/all/`

After send request you get Json data that you can ues it.

see above Link :

[Using HTTP Methods (GET, POST, PUT, etc.) in Web API](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/using-http-methods-correctly-in-asp-net-web-api/)

[Calling Web API from a Windows Phone 8 Application](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/mobile-clients/calling-web-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-application)

[Building Web APIs for Mobile Apps Using ASP.NET Web API 2.1](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-603)